# Basics: Importing a class in groovy

Tags: visual-studio, groovy, vscode-code-runner

I'm beating my head over this but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a folder "myproject" and two files in it - "MyScript.groovy" and "MyClass.groovy".

**MyClass.groovy**

```
package myproject

public class MyClass {
    void printHello() {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

**MyScript.groovy**

```
package myproject
import myproject.MyClass

def myObject = new MyClass()
myObject.printHello()
```

When I try to run MyScript.groovy, I get the following error:

```
[Running] groovy "c:\Users\myUser\...\myproject\MyScript.groovy"
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\myUser\...\myproject\MyScript.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class myproject.MyClass
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import myproject.MyClass
   ^

1 error
```

I don't think, this is relevant, but I'm running it via the Code Runner Extension in Visual Studio.
Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without further configuration Groovy assumes the current working
directory to be (part of the) classpath.  So your setup is basically
correct; assuming it is like this:

```
# find .
.
./myproject
./myproject/MyClass.groovy
./myproject/MyScript.groovy
```

So running this where package structure and directory structure match,
it works:

```
# groovy myproject/MyScript.groovy 
hello
```

So your most likely problem here is, that either your IDE is not setting
the cwd correctly or you have configured `.../myproject` as the project
root.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using classes from a separate project directory.

This worked for me:
In the settings for code runner (file > pereferences > settings > search for "runner" )

I added/updated this in the executorMap setting:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "groovy": "groovy -cp \".;src;vars;C:\\GitRepositories\\my-other-library\\src\"",
}
```

When you then run the code you'll see the command updated with the classpath shown.

*I know this question is old, but I couldn't find the answer and thought this may help others*